# Intercepting incoming/outgoing emails for android

Tags: android, email

I have an app where i need to monitor incoming/outgoing gmail e-mails. Now, for SMS, similar sort of monitoring is possible with a Broadcast receiver listening to android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED.
 I was wondering if same thing is possible for emails also. Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This seems to indicate that what you are looking to do is not going to be possible on a wide array of devices. And, even if you happen to find a way, it is likely that it will quit working at some point.

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ced02d814d411ac0/e87f23d06df43828?lnk=raot&pli=1